# Problem with FourierTransform

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let us consider

```
a = FourierTransform[Log[RealAbs[x]]*Sin[x], x, s]
```

> $\frac{i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}}{2 \left| s+1\right| }-\frac{i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}}{2 \left| s-1\right| } $

and

```
b = FourierTransform[Log[Abs[x]]*Sin[x], x, s]
```

> $$-\frac{i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}}{2 \left| s-1\right| }+\frac{i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}}{2 \left| s+1\right| }-i \gamma  \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \delta (s-1)+\gamma  i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \delta (s+1) $$

The outputs should be the same, but the ones differ. Well it happens. Let us verify both results by

```
InverseFourierTransform[a, s, x]
```

> $ -\frac{1}{2} i e^{-i x} \left(-1+e^{2 i x}\right) (\log (\left| x\right| )+\gamma )$

and

```
InverseFourierTransform[b, s, x]
```

> $ -\frac{1}{2} i e^{-i x} \left(-1+e^{2 i x}\right) \log (\left| x\right| )$

OK, it seems `b` is correct, `a` isn't. However, it is not so simple.

First, both Fourier transforms do not exist in traditional sense because of

```
Integrate[Log[RealAbs[x]]*Sin[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> Integrate::idiv:Integral of Log[RealAbs[x]] Sin[x] does not converge on {-[Infinity],[Infinity]}.

(see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)).

Second, I find the formula for `b` in neither the cited Wiki article nor Kammler, David (2000), A First Course in Fourier Analysis, Prentice Hall, ISBN 978-0-13-578782-3 nor Erdélyi, Arthur, ed. (1954), Tables of Integral Transforms, Vol. 1, McGraw-Hill.

Third, Maple produces another expression for `b` without any deltas (also confirmed by the command of Maple for inverse Fourier transform).  I am aware of the difference in the definitions used in Maple and Mathematica. That difference is not so principal.

The questions arise: what's the origin of the output of  `b`? may we trust in it?